# Can there exist a unit root series that’s Granger-caused, or better predicted with a model other than the AR process we tested using ADF?

Tags: forecasting, autoregressive, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller, granger-causality

If a series has a unit root, then it is a function of random white noise. Therefore, it follows a random walk process.

Is it then possible for:

1. Some other series to Granger-cause the unit root series?
2. Another model to predict the unit root series better than the AR process we tested for when conducting the ADF? I.e. a random walk process with drift, trend.

Effectively, are we “done,” as many say, when we find a unit root in a series? I.e. you’re wasting your time trying to find a better model than the AR process we tested using ADF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The premise is incorrect. A series that has a unit root need not be a random walk series. Take any stationary series that is not white noise and then take its cumulatively sums for each time point. The new series will contain a unit root yet it will not be a random walk.

Now to your questions:

1. Yes, it is possible for other series to Granger-cause a unit-root series. Take a pair of cointegrated time series that each have a unit root, and you will find that at least one of them causes the other (or perhaps both cause each other). For a detailed exposition, see Giles ["Cointegration & Granger Causality"](https://davegiles.blogspot.com/2015/10/cointegration-granger-causality.html).
2. In such a case and given a sufficiently long time series (so that model coefficients can be estimated with good precision) a vector error correction model will do a better job forecasting your unit-root series (the one that is Granger-caused by the other) than an AR model would.

Comment: Thank you. But if the first differences of a series are not autocorrelated and are stationary, then the original series is a random walk right?

Comment: @user10136297, there are several definitions of a random walk. The loosest of them fits your description. For details, see p. 31-33 of Campbell et al. ["The Econometrics of Financial Markets"](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691043012/the-econometrics-of-financial-markets) (1996).

Comment: Thanks Richard.

Comment: @user10136297, you are welcome!

Comment: By the way, if I have two time series that clearly trend together, but are non stationary… and I find that the first differences of the time series are not correlated at all even with a bunch of lags… what’s the right way to interpret that? My series are financial time series.. so they clearly trend together but have no relationship in first differences. Would I say they “aren’t actually related?”

Comment: @user10136297, if both contain unit roots, look for cointegration and Granger causality. If they do not contain unit roots, see if you can model their trends with some deterministic components and see how the residuals of the two series relate to each other. In general, if you see a relationship visually, then the question is how to represent that with a model. I would trust the visual to a large degree and be suspicious of models that do not reflect the visually obvious relationship. Though some relationships are spurious, that we have to keep in mind, too.

Comment: So last question if you don’t mind: if I am purely interested in describing what happened in the past, there isn’t any problem with me running correlations on the non stationary levels, right?? The more I run analyses on the first differences the sillier it seems - these series are very much related in levels and my first differenced analysis is essentially telling me “nope nothing to see here.”….

Comment: @user10136297, that is an interesting and nontrivial question. I doubt correlation has much statistical meaning when applied on a pair of nonstationary, noncointegrated time series. There is a geometric meaning (a certain line can be drawn through a plot of historical data, and the data is distributed around it in a certain way), but is that what you want? Statistically, reporting a correlation between a pair of time series implicitly suggests an assumption of stationarity. So when you report a correlation, your audience is likely to assume stationarity (whether they can articulate it or not).

Comment: @user10136297, I think I would avoid reporting correlation of nonstationary, noncointegrated time series unless I knew very well what I am doing and were able to explain myself well to the audience. Otherwise the message that gets through might be quite different from the one you may be trying to send.